# Kasten k10 dashboard 504 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, kubernetes, port-forwarding, rbac

I Have installed the Kasten k10 on AWS k8, trying to access the dashboard from service port forward.

Dashboard has an network error with error logs on dashboard-svc pod and Gateway pod.

[image]

Below are the Logs from gateway pod

Gateway pod logs -

"GET /k10/dashboardbff-svc/v0/licenseStatus HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0 321 68 64 "10.112.16.161" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "aa945eae-16e9-46c4-a1a5-dcef95116844" "127.0.0.1:8080" "172.20.107.124:8000"

ACCESS [2024-02-14T17:04:38.709Z] "GET /k10/dashboardbff-svc/v0/bff/policycrs/kasten-io HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0 3 33 31 "10.112.16.161" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "05c54010-8936-4a4d-a0a6-ae7f16d1dc61" "127.0.0.1:8080" "172.20.107.124:8000"

2024-02-14 17:04:52 diagd 3.9.1 [P16TThreadPoolExecutor-0_0] INFO: B9D8651D-8E09-48D6-87DD-1C5C091D0904: 127.0.0.1 "GET /metrics" 9ms 200 success

ACCESS [2024-02-14T17:04:56.721Z] "POST /k10/dashboardbff-svc/v0/log HTTP/1.1" 201 - 262 0 11 8 "10.112.16.161" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "b9ccba0a-6430-4c2e-ad16-7935b9d219cc" "127.0.0.1:8080" "172.20.107.124:8000"

2024-02-14 17:05:04 diagd 3.9.1 [P16TAEW] INFO: -global-:

2024-02-14 17:05:04 diagd 3.9.1 [P16TAEW] ERROR: ERROR ERROR ERROR Starting with configuration errors

dashboard svc logs -

Error: {"message":"Fluentbit connection error","function":"kasten.io/k10/kio/log/hooks/fluentbit.(*Hook).handle","linenumber":97,"file":"kasten.io/k10/kio/log/hooks/fluentbit/fluentbit.go:97","cause":{"message":"Fluentbit connection problem","function":"kasten.io/k10/kio/log/hooks/fluentbit.(*Hook).dial","linenumber":88,"file":"kasten.io/k10/kio/log/hooks/fluentbit/fluentbit.go:88","cause":{"message":"dial tcp 172.20.139.224:24224: i/o timeout"}}}

Log message dropped (buffer): {"File":"kasten.io/k10/rest/srv/dashboardbffserver/kio_frontend_log_handler.go","Function":"kasten.io/k10/rest/srv/dashboardbffserver.(*frontendLogHandler).log","Level":"error","Line":34,"Message":"Response data","Time":"2024-02-14T17:05:39.097668169Z","cluster_name":"e64de663-d66a-4f1e-8b3b-f24789bd70a0","data":["upstream request timeout"],"hostname":"dashboardbff-svc-74477d7749-lxwjz","origin":"frontend","sessionId":"5f4294d0-e66c-4fc0-a864-3dab4a12efc9","version":"6.5.4"}

{"File":"kasten.io/k10/rest/srv/dashboardbffserver/kio_frontend_log_handler.go","Function":"kasten.io/k10/rest/srv/dashboardbffserver.(*frontendLogHandler).log","Level":"info","Line":30,"Message":"Network error debug info","Time":"2024-02-14T17:05:39.09785307Z","cluster_name":"e64de663-d66a-4f1e-8b3b-f24789bd70a0","data":[],"hostname":"dashboardbff-svc-74477d7749-lxwjz","origin":"frontend","sessionId":"5f4294d0-e66c-4fc0-a864-3dab4a12efc9","version":"6.5.4"}

{"File":"kasten.io/k10/rest/srv/dashboardbffserver/kio_frontend_log_handler.go","Function":"kasten.io/k10/rest/srv/dashboardbffserver.(*frontendLogHandler).log","Level":"error","Line":34,"Message":"Response status","Time":"2024-02-14T17:05:39.114611471Z","cluster_name":"e64de663-d66a-4f1e-8b3b-f24789bd70a0","data":[504],"hostname":"dashboardbff-svc-74477d7749-lxwjz","origin":"frontend","sessionId":"5f4294d0-e66c-4fc0-a864-3dab4a12efc9","version":"6.5.4"}

{"File":"kasten.io/k10/rest/srv/dashboardbffserver/kio_frontend_log_handler.go","Function":"kasten.io/k10/rest/srv/dashboardbffserver.(*frontendLogHandler).log","Level":"error","Line":34,"Message":"Response headers","Time":"2024-02-14T17:05:39.133562583Z","cluster_name":"e64de663-d66a-4f1e-8b3b-f24789bd70a0","data":[{"content-length":"24","content-type":"text/plain","date":"Wed, 14 Feb 2024 17:05:38 GMT","server":"envoy"}],"hostname":"dashboardbff-svc-74477d7749-lxwjz","origin":"frontend","sessionId":"5f4294d0-e66c-4fc0-a864-3dab4a12efc9","version":"6.5.4"}